# Does a https connection automatically encrypts the data with ssl

Tags: iphone, ios, http, ssl, https

I am just programming a iPhone application and I want to establish a https connection to the client's server. So far I have used ASIHTTPRequest.

What I learned so far is that I need a certificate to have a https connection to the server. But I have also to encrypt the data exchange with ssl. Is this done on the background? So I mean - is that done by ASIHTTPRequest, CFNetwork or maybe NSURLConnection or anything else. If not how can I realize this?

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking if you need to encrypt the data yourself, the answer is no. The underlying Objective-C libraries will take care of that for you as long as you send your data over HTTPS and not HTTP.